# Spring Boot Maven Application Containerized with Docker - build WAR based on profile flag

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-profiles, maven-profiles

I have a spring boot application that makes use of profile files 'application-dev.properties' and 'application-test.properties'. The project is containerized by using Docker, look at the code below.

Running 'RUN mvn package' works, but I want to build based on one of the profiles. Is there a way I can achieve this? Because "RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -P test" doesn't seem like to work..

```
 FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine as build-env
 COPY pom.xml /tmp/
 COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml
 COPY src /tmp/src/

 WORKDIR /tmp/
 RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -P test

 FROM tomcat:8.0
 COPY --from=build-env /tmp/target/cbm-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/cbm- server.war

 EXPOSE 8009
 EXPOSE 8080
 CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a profile to the runtime phase.
You can do it with an environment variable.

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=test"
```

Comment: Isnt it possible to place a flag in the Dockerfile to decide the profile file? Or will that not work?

Comment: It's not possible in the build phase, it's possible in runtime but you are using war and you have to use environment variables or tomcat variables

Comment: You can also use the maven resource plugin which can move application-test.properties to application.properties and you will achieve goal.

Comment: I created a setevn.sh file and I my dockerfile I copy it to the here "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh". I think this will work!

Comment: Do I only need to use the word "test"? Because the file is named "application-test.properties".

Comment: you can use any string as profile and string have to be suffix to properties name.
<profile> application-<profile>.<properties|Yaml>